# I want to fetch first five rows and display same 5 five rows at different places on single page using single query

Tags: php

I want to fetch first five rows and display same five rows at different places on single page, using single query

```
$cel_bir1=$db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_birthday WHERE MONTH(Birthday_Date)=$month AND DAY(Birthday_Date)=$day LIMIT 4"); 
$get_bir=$cel_bir1->fetch(); $count=0; 
while($get_bir1=$cel_bir1->fetch())
{ 
    if($count++) echo ','; 
    echo $get_bir1['Name']; 
}
```

Comment: show your code what you have done so far

Comment: That is a statement, not  a question! What have you tried so far?

Comment: $cel_bir1=$db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_birthday WHERE MONTH(Birthday_Date)=$month AND DAY(Birthday_Date)=$day LIMIT 4");
   $get_bir=$cel_bir1->fetch();
   $count=0;                                               while($get_bir1=$cel_bir1->fetch()){                                                             
             if($count++) echo ',';  
        echo $get_bir1['Name'];                                                                      
     }

Comment: Please share the code of what you have tried.

Comment: I want to display  $get_bir1['Name'];  at 4 places on my page . But want to use single query. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Try repeating the while loop twice like $cel_bir1=$db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_birthday WHERE MONTH(Birthday_Date)=$month AND DAY(Birthday_Date)=$day LIMIT 4"); 
$get_bir=$cel_bir1->fetch(); $count=0; 
while($get_bir1=$cel_bir1->fetch())
{ //loop1
    if($count++) echo ','; 
    echo $get_bir1['Name']; 
} while($get_bir1=$cel_bir1->fetch())
{ //loop2
    if($count++) echo ','; 
    echo $get_bir1['Name']; 
}

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 0,5";
// $conn = your connection to database
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);
$html = '';
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
$html.= $row['colum1'].'<br>'.$row['colum2'];
}
echo $html;
?>
// some more html code
<?php echo $html?>
// some more html code
<?php echo $html?>
// some more html code
<?php echo $html?>
```

Answer (score 0):

So to get the first 5 rows, you can use Mysql Limit eg: Select * FROM mytable LIMIT 5.

Ok, typically what happens is, When using a PDO,your result-set is stored in an array.

```
$query = "Select * FROM mytable";

$statement = $db->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$productsinfo = $statement->fetchAll();//$productsinfo is the array in question

$statement->closeCursor();
```

Now to get the values in the array, you can loop through the array using a foreach loop like:

```
foreach($productsinfo as $productsinfomation):
$productid=$productsinfomation['productid'];
//you can echo $productid or anything you want to do with it here
endforeach;
```

There is no harm in repeating the foreach loop at different positions on your page.

Le'me know how it works for you.
Have fun coding.

Comment: I want to display first five names in my header description using my coding

Comment: Ok try: $cel_bir1=$db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_birthday WHERE MONTH(Birthday_Date)=$month AND DAY(Birthday_Date)=$day LIMIT 4"); 
$get_bir=$cel_bir1->fetch(); $count=0; 
while($get_bir1=$cel_bir1->fetch())
{ //first loop
    if($count++) echo ','; 
    echo $get_bir1['Name']; 
} while($get_bir1=$cel_bir1->fetch())
{ //second loop
    if($count++) echo ','; 
    echo $get_bir1['Name']; 
} Let me know how it works

Comment: It does not display anything where i place second loop

Comment: Ok let me try something out

Comment: Try repeating the while loop twice like $cel_bir1=$db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_birthday WHERE MONTH(Birthday_Date)=$month AND DAY(Birthday_Date)=$day LIMIT 4"); 
$get_bir=$cel_bir1->fetch(); $count=0; 
while($get_bir1=$cel_bir1->fetch())
{ //loop1
    if($count++) echo ','; 
    echo $get_bir1['Name']; 
} while($get_bir1=$cel_bir1->fetch())
{ //loop2
    if($count++) echo ','; 
    echo $get_bir1['Name']; 
}